# Finding eigenfunctions and eigenvalues.

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors

So the first part of this question was already asked but the answer was found using a method not mentioned in the question. The substitution of x = e^t is important. Here is the question:

By substituting $x = e^t$, find the normalized eigenfunctions $y_n(x)$ and the eigen-values $λ_n$ of the operator $L$ defined by $$Ly=x^2y′′+ 2xy′+\dfrac{1}{4}y$$ over $$1≤x≤e$$ with $y(1)=y(e)=0$. Assume that the weight function is unity. Find, as a series $\sum_n a_ny_n(x)$, the solution of $Ly=x^{−1/2}$ subject to the same boundary conditions.

Comment: I have a question... $y'$ stands for $\frac{dy}{dx}$ or for $\frac{dy}{dt}$?

Comment: It initially stands for dy/dx I believe. I don't know if you have to change it though or what.